# Hide/show li items based on the category filter clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of li items whose categories have been added to the class. 1 means it is associated with that category, 0 means it is not. When first visiting the page, they will all appear "View All". Clicking "Fruits" will show all items that have "fruits-1" in them. Clicking "View All" will show ALL items.

Filter by:

```
<ul>

<li><a href="">View All</a></li>
<li><a href="">Fruits</a></li>
<li><a href="">Vegetables</a></li>
<li><a href="">Nuts</a></li>
<li><a href="">Desserts & Cakes</a></li>

</ul>

<ul>
<li class="fruits-1 nuts-0 vegetables-1 desserts-1">Product 1</li>
<li class="fruits-0 nuts-1 vegetables-0 desserts-1">Product 2</li>
<li class="fruits-1 nuts-1 vegetables-1 desserts-0">Product 3</li>
<li class="fruits-0 nuts-1 vegetables-0 desserts-0">Product 4</li>
<li class="fruits-1 nuts-0 vegetables-1 desserts-0">Product 5</li>
<li class="fruits-0 nuts-1 vegetables-0 desserts-0">Product 6</li>
<li class="fruits-0 nuts-0 vegetables-0 desserts-1">Product 7</li>
<li class="fruits-1 nuts-0 vegetables-1 desserts-0">Product 8</li>
</ul>
```

What should I do to these items (add classes or ID's or whatever) to make it so when I click a category, only the ones that belong to that category appear? and the rest are hidden?

Comment: Multiple classes should be separated with space, not comma.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j8Lnt8w4/24/

Comment: My CMS outputs my filters separated by commas :( Is there anyway around this using javascript?

Comment: Just made an edit, please amend anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this : you can use text of clicked anchor to find matching categories and show them. see below code

```js
$(function(){
  $('ul li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var category = $(this).text().toLowerCase().split("&");
    if(category[0]=="view all")
    {
      $('ul.category li').show();
    }
    else
    {
       //hide all categories
       $('ul.category li').hide();
       $.each(category, function(i, v){
         $('ul.category li.'+v.trim()+"-1").show();
       });
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

<li><a href="">View All</a></li>
<li><a href="">Fruits</a></li>
<li><a href="">Vegetables</a></li>
<li><a href="">Nuts</a></li>
<li><a href="">Desserts & Cakes</a></li>

</ul>

<ul class="category">
<li class="fruits-1 nuts-0 vegetables-1 desserts-1">Product 1</li>
<li class="fruits-0 nuts-1 vegetables-0 desserts-1">Product 2</li>
<li class="fruits-1 nuts-1 vegetables-1 desserts-0">Product 3</li>
<li class="fruits-0 nuts-1 vegetables-0 desserts-0">Product 4</li>
<li class="fruits-1 nuts-0 vegetables-1 desserts-0">Product 5</li>
<li class="fruits-0 nuts-1 vegetables-0 desserts-0">Product 6</li>
<li class="fruits-0 nuts-0 vegetables-0 desserts-1">Product 7</li>
<li class="fruits-1 nuts-0 vegetables-1 desserts-0">Product 8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What if I have a category that is two words like "Desserts & Cakes" ?

Comment: then you need to modify the logic so that you will read these two clasess and put same in jquery selectors. Example you need to split `Desserts & Cakes` into  array, iterate array and apply it for jquery selection. see my updated answer

Comment: Is there anyway it can be done with commas in there. My CMS won't output anything except separating each category with commas. Is there another way? Perhaps we don't use classes or data tag?

Comment: Nevermind my previous format, I have just amended it, is this one easier to work with?

Comment: yeah this is very easy to work with. But if you want to use with comma in class values like `class="veg,fruit,drink"` then replace `$('ul.category li.'+v.trim()).show();` this line with `$('ul.category li.').filter(function(){ return $(this).attr('class').indexOf(v.trim()) != -1;}).show();` this code

Comment: I want to use my new format, can you write up the javascript for me so I can Run code snippet? And will award you as the Answer thanks please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88745/discussion-between-kim-tran-and-bhushan-kawadkar).

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have this

```
<ul class="listed-values">

   <li class="fruit,veg,nuts,drink">Product 1</li>
   <li class="drink">Product 2</li>
   <li class="veg,nuts,drink">Product 3</li>
   <li class="veg,nuts">Product 4</li>

</ul>
```

and this one

```
<ul class="filter-ul">

  <li><a href="">Fruit</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Veg</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Nuts</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Drink</a></li>

</ul>
```

Here is jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".filter-ul li a").click(function(){
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        $('ul.listed-values li').hide();
        $('ul.listed-values li').filter(function(){
           return $(this).attr('class').indexOf(text) != -1;
        }).show();
    })
})
```

Comment: `(this).text().toLowerCase()` won't work for `Drinks`, because the class just contains `drink`.

Comment: brother you can remove **s** from it :)

Comment: What if I have a category that is two words like "Desserts & Cakes" ?

Comment: you have to change the logic then change the selectors

Comment: Nevermind my previous format, I have just amended it, is this one easier to work with?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.links li a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var className = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
  $(".content li").not('.' + className).hide();
  $(".content li" + "." + className).show();
})
```

```css
.content li{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="links">
  <li><a href="">Fruit</a> </li>
  <li><a href="">Veg</a> </li>
  <li><a href="">Nuts</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Drinks</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="content">
  <li class="fruit veg nuts drinks">Product 1</li>
  <li class="drinks">Product 2</li>
  <li class="veg nuts drinks">Product 3</li>
  <li class="veg nuts">Product 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What if I have a category that is two words like "Desserts & Cakes" ?

Comment: @kim Tran in that case barmer's answer is better.

Comment: Nevermind my previous format, I have just amended it, is this one easier to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `data-category` attribute to each filter to indicate which category it should display. Then use that in a selector to match the class of the products.

The proper way to separate multiple classes is with spaces, not commas.

```js
$("#filters a").click(function() {
  var category = $(this).data("category");
  $("#products li").hide();
  $("#products li." + category).show();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="products">

  <li class="fruit veg nuts drink">Product 1</li>
  <li class="drink">Product 2</li>
  <li class="veg nuts drink">Product 3</li>
  <li class="veg nuts">Product 4</li>

</ul>

Filter by:

<ul id="filters">

  <li><a href="" data-category="fruit">Fruit</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-category="veg">Veg</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-category="nuts">Nuts</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-category="drink">Drinks</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `html` classes are separated with spaces not with comma.

html code:

```
<ul class="products">
    <li class="fruit veg nuts drink">Product 1</li>
    <li class="drink">Product 2</li>
    <li class="veg nuts drink">Product 3</li>
    <li class="veg nuts">Product 4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a href="" class='category'>Fruit</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class='category'>Veg</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class='category'>Nuts</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class='category'>Drinks</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS Code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".category").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var products = $(".products").find("li"); 
        products.show();

        var cat = $(this).text();
        products.not('.'+cat.toLowerCase()).hide();
    });
});
```

You can find the working demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/crL054px/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

JS Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/cfzdq7f7/

**HTML**

```
<ul>

<li class="fruit veg nuts drink">Product 1</li>
<li class="drink">Product 2</li>
<li class="veg nuts drink">Product 3</li>
<li class="veg nuts">Product 4</li>

</ul>


<ul>

<li class="category">Fruit</li>
<li class="category">Veg</li>
<li class="category">Nuts</li>
<li class="category">Drinks</li>

</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".category").click(function() {
      if($(this).html() == "Fruit") {
        $(".veg").hide();
        $(".nuts").hide();
        $(".drink").hide();
        $(".fruit").show();
      } else if($(this).html() == "Veg") {
        $(".fruit").hide();
        $(".nuts").hide();
        $(".drink").hide();
        $(".veg").show();
      } else if($(this).html() == "Nuts") {
        $(".fruit").hide();
        $(".veg").hide();
        $(".drink").hide();
        $(".nuts").show();
      } else if($(this).html() == "Drinks") {
        $(".fruit").hide();
        $(".nuts").hide();
        $(".veg").hide();
        $(".drink").show();
      }
   });

});
```

**CSS**

```
.fruit, .veg, .nuts, .drink {
    display:none;
}
.category {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Let me know if it is helpful